# How do I force replace local repo with git repo

Tags: git, github

I have git repo and I cloned it to my local. Changes code and I committed then pushed to git. My local code is working fine but when I download it from git, it is not working. Even I have tried `git push -f` but its saying *already up to date* . Even I have tried every possibility. So my exact question is here that something is missing from git repo so how can i completely replace my local repo with git repo.

Comment: Question is not very clear. You are downloading the repo from git which you just pushed. Can you give me example ?

Comment: Can you give some more detail? What is the local repo - how was it set up? is it on a remote server somewhere or set up as a bare repo on the file system and then you cloned it somewhere else on the file system? Give some exact commands on what you've done when changing/committing/pushing and then what you've done when "downloading". What do you mean "it is not working"?

Comment: When I clone it, it is working awesome, but when I download it in zip, damn the code itself not working. I don't know where is exact issue in downloading.